# Fetch JSON API real time

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I want to update the DOM for all the users, while fetching some data from an API.
This is for an NFT project and I want to update the number of NFTs left, so I'm using a timer, but I feel that the page is lagging a bit. How can I improve this?

```
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const signal = controller.signal;
  const fetchMintedNFTs = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(mintedNFTs(smartContract), {signal});
    const data = await response.json();
      setalreadyMintedNFTs(data);
      setLoadingMintedNFTs(false);
  };
  const interval = setInterval(() => fetchMintedNFTs(), 10000);
  
  useEffect(() => 
  {

  },[fetchMintedNFTs(),interval]);
```

I'm fetching this https://devnet-api.elrond.com/nfts/count?creator=

Answer (score 0):

i think use fetch with interval is not recomended in this case.
i suggest use websocket instead.
with websocket you can get data realtime and not need call the api with interval, because websocket connection is bidirectional